# Swift - How to create local variables to use from the API data in mapViewkit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to replace the latitude and longitude with the data coming from API, I just don't know how to call them from the MapViewController, all are set up just how to call them from the structure I created and connected with the APICaller.swift

The Vehicles.swift structure:

```swift
struct Vehicles: Codable {
    var IDVehicle: Int?
    var Title: String?
    var RegistrationDate: String?
    var ExpireDate: String?
    var Department: String?
    var Identification: String?
    var Speed: String?
    var Latitude: Double?
    var Longitude: Double?
    var Angle: Int?
    var Status: Int?
    var InputValue: Int?
    var Plate: String?
    var LastCommunicationDate: String?
    var Passengers: Int?
    var Driver: String?
}
```

Now I need to put the Latitude and Longtitude in here "another viewController" :

```swift
let appleHQ = CLLocation(latitude: 37.334722 , longitude: 37.334722)
let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000.0
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: appleHQ.coordinate, latitudinalMeters:        regionRadius, longitudinalMeters: regionRadius)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
mapView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class APIManager{
    
    static var sharedInstance:APIManager = APIManager()
    
    func apiCallerToFetchData(completion:(Result<Vehicles,Error>)->()){
        //NetworkCall
        //After Getting Response assign that value ,but below i put as static code
        let vechicle = Vehicles(IDVehicle: 1, Title: "", RegistrationDate: "", ExpireDate: "", Department: "", Identification: "", Speed: "", Angle: 1, Status: 1, InputValue: 1, Plate: "", LastCommunicationDate: "", Passengers: 1)
        completion(.success(vechicle))
    }
}

class MapViewController: UIViewController {
  var globalVechicle = Vehicles()
  var localLattitude :Double?
  var localLongitude :Double? 

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchDataFromAPI {_ in
            updateUIHere()
        }
    }
    
    func updateUIHere(){
//you can either using globalVechicle.lattitude or localLattitude while assigning the value
        guard let lattitude = globalVechicle.Latitude ,let longitude = globalVechicle.Longitude else { return }
        let appleHQ = CLLocation(latitude: lattitude  , longitude: longitude)
        let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000.0
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: appleHQ.coordinate, latitudinalMeters:        regionRadius, longitudinalMeters: regionRadius)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        mapView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func fetchDataFromAPI(completion:(Bool)->()){
        APIManager.sharedInstance.apiCallerToFetchData { result in
            switch result{
            case .success(let vechicle):
                globalVechicle = vechicle
               localLattitude = vechicle.Latitude
               localLongitude = vechicle.Longitude

                completion(true)
            case .failure(let Error)
                completion(false)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @L1S ,this is the way you wanna do with

Comment: check the below code please

Comment: hey man the code is working just not showing the excact location as API?